# Android Word-Wrap EditText text

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, word-wrap, text-segmentation

I have been trying to get my EditText box to word wrap, but can't seem to do it.

I have dealt with much more complicated issues while developing Android applications, and this seems like it should be a straightforward process.

However, the issue remains, and I have a large text box that is only allowing me to enter text on one line, continuing straight across, scrolling horizontally as I enter text.

Here is the XML code for the EditText object from my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myWidget48"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget37"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNotes"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Besides finding the source of the issue, I found the solution. If `android:inputType` is used, then textMultiLine must be used to enable multi-line support. Also, using inputType supersedes the code `android:singleLine="false"`. If using inputType, then, to reiterate, textMultiLine must be used or the EditText object will only consist of one line, without word-wrapping.

**Edit:** Thank you **Jacob Malliet** for providing further good advice on this. He suggested to set the boolean scrollHorizontally property to false, `'android:scrollHorizontally="false"'`.

Example XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id ="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width ="0dip" 
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" 
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines ="4" 
    android:maxLength ="2000" 
    android:hint ="@string/compose_hint"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Comment: What I missed was android:layout_width = "0dp"

Comment: Why do you use `android:layout_width ="0dip"`? It is invisible for me, as I supposed.

Comment: @Error404 // it will be overriden by `layout_weight="1"` attribute. So it might be placed in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: For those who can't get this solution to work, just wrap it inside a linearlayout (like the one OP wrapped it in) and it should work fine.

Comment: The only thing required is ```textMultiLine```, rest of the details are unnecessary

Answer (score 26):

Ok i figured it out, you must set `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` for your `EditText` in your xml. I'm pretty sure this should work.

Comment: five different answers, this is the only one that worked for me (besides the ghastly table one which I didn't even try)

Comment: This is THE answer. No need `Lines`, `minLines`. `maxLines` and `android:scrollHorizontally="false"`, and `inputType` can make it.

Answer (score 21):

Assume that you just want to have one line at first then expand it to 5 lines and you want to have maximum 10 lines.

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/etMessageBox"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:autoLink="all"
   android:hint="@string/message_edit_text_hint"
   android:lines="5"
   android:minLines="1"
   android:gravity="top|left"
   android:maxLines="10"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"/>
```

By increasing `android:lines` you can define expand it how many lines.

Answer (score 19):

you must add the following attribute to your edittext.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Also if you set the height or set the maxlines of edittext to a specific value, it will scroll when you typed much character.

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out.  The line,

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

was the issue.  Adding this line to an EditText object will make the object be a single line EditText, and will not let words wrap, or allow a user to press 'Enter' to insert a line feed or carriage return in the EditText.

Comment: Well then, just use `android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"` instead. Then your EditText field will start with uppercase _and_ it will be multi-line. It works for me! Now I see you've put that in a separate answer above anyway...

Answer (score 6):

Enclosing the entire activity in scroll view and placing the following edit text with in linear layout worked like a charm for me.

The edit text would scroll itself vertically pressing enter, code as follows

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter somehting"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:maxLines="6"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

Comment: `"Enter somehting"` :D But who cares ;) #Typo

Answer (score 3):

Try this, changing gravity to top|left worked for me, along with input type textmultiline

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/color_red"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:lines="10"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="26sp" />
```

Comment: Please use `top|start` instead of `top|left`, for rtl support.

Answer (score 1):

For those doing it programmatically, you might want to look at this question [Android EditText Multiline does not work as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294498/android-edittext-multiline-does-not-work-as-it-should)
 to double check you are setting the input type correctly. That was my issue

Answer (score 0):

Also set the **parent layout width**, *(Layout_width property)* . For example **layout_width=250sp**

otherwise , EditText or TextView dont wrap to next line till it reach the end of mobile border. So define the Layout_width

Comment: Parent means, LinerLayout or Tablelayout etc

Answer (score -1):

Note: 
step 1 - create a custom class for `EditText` wordWrap.

Android hasn't this property. But you can replace all breaking characters with ReplacementTransformationMethod.

```java
public class WordBreakTransformationMethod extends ReplacementTransformationMethod
{
    private static WordBreakTransformationMethod instance;
    private WordBreakTransformationMethod() {}

    public static WordBreakTransformationMethod getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new WordBreakTransformationMethod();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static char[] dash = new char[] {'-', '\u2011'};
    private static char[] space = new char[] {' ', '\u00A0'};

    private static char[] original = new char[] {dash[0], space[0]};
    private static char[] replacement = new char[] {dash[1], space[1]};

    @Override
    protected char[] getOriginal()
    {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getReplacement()
    {
        return replacement;
    }
}
```

Step 2 - In Activity , write below code,

In Android :

```java
myEditText.setTransformationMethod(WordBreakTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
myEditText.setTransformationMethod= WordBreakTransformationMethod.getInstance
```

In Xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It works in my edittext.

```
 android:gravity="top|start"
```

Answer (score -6):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >  
     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/newRow">
        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="left"
             android:paddingBottom="10dip">
            <TextView  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Some Text"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dip">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editbox"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:gravity="top"   
        android:inputType="textFilter"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"      
        />  

</RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnone"  
        android:layout_width="3dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn"
        />          
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btntwo"  
        android:layout_width="3dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn"
        />    
 </LinearLayout>
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: please provide some details of this answer