# EditText with single text line, line wrapping and Done action?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to have an `EditText` with the following characteristics when editing with a soft key. I ready the documentation, searched here, play with the parameters but could not find a working configuration.

1. The `EditView` view on the screen has height for a few lines (e.g. 3-4).
2. The content text is a single line (that is, no line breaks).
3. If the content text is longer than the view's width it should wrap to next line
4. The Enter key of the soft key shows the Done action label.

I could achieve {1,2,3} and {1,2,4} but not {1,2,3,4}. My rational is that since the content is a single line (no line breaks) the Enter key is not used and thus should be able to be changed to the Done label.

My setup code looks like this

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
editText.setSingleLine(false);
// This does not work. Soft keyboard has Enter action.
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Is it possible? Any suggestion?

Comment: Can anybody at least confirm that this cannot be done?

Comment: Line wrapping outlined in the answer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276380/android-word-wrap-edittext-text

Comment: Thanks A T. Yes, this does wrapping but how to I get it to work with required #4 above?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Remove the inputtype MULTILINE.  and then set the property  maxLines via code to 3 or 4, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 38):

This combination (and the specific order of the `EditText` method calls) should produce the configuration that you want:

```
  editText.setInputType(
    InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
  editText.setSingleLine(true);
  editText.setLines(4); // desired number of lines
  editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
  editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Comment: AWESOME! Virtual hug for you :)

Comment: to change height dynamically use setMaxLines instead

Comment: Thx for correct answer, as others told EditText have hidden implicit contracts when setting it's properties so operation order is important. To achieve starting with single line EditText and than autowrap to next line until maxLines are reached just replace:

editText.setLines(4) ; 
with:
editText.setMaxLines(maxLines = 5);

Comment: @Joe Thank you for your answer. Would you please be so nice and expand your answer and explain how on earth did you come up with that combination. Very useful.

Answer (score 9):

Just add

```
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
editText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

with your edittext instance in your activity programmatically.

It configures the EditText instance so that the user edits a single-line string that is displayed with soft-wrapping on multiple lines with IME options.

Comment: Just to be clear, you cannot set these values in your layout XML--they will be ignored. Set them programmatically just like the OP says to.