# EditText with word-wrap, without line breaks, and with keyboard action set to "next"

Tags: android, android-edittext

This has been asked a lot of times ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351254/edittext-with-single-text-line-line-wrapping-and-done-action), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276380/android-word-wrap-edittext-text), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205985/edittext-word-wrap), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842421/android-edittext-with-word-wrap-but-no-hard-returns)…) but that was long ago, and neither of the answers work for me now. Hence posting the new question rather than bumping the old ones. Sorry for the duplicate.

I need to have an EditText, where:

- it disallows line breaks;
- on-screen keyboard should show "next" button instead of line break;
- originally it is one line high;
- but when content overflows, it wraps on words like multi-line text.

If you have Gmail or Inbox app, I need exactly the functionality of email subject field.

Here's the approximate picture — only that the keyboard should show an › button, not a caret button.

[image: Screenshot]

I've been trying all kinds of EditText properties and their combinations, including ones with `android:inputType="textEmailSubject"`, but I always either have it single-line and not wrapping, or I have this caret button and it allows for line breaks. Another interesting fact is that I can get it to work with a non-stock keyboard (AnySoftKeyboard), but not with the stock one.

Please help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out you have to do this by code because some XML attributes get ignored in particular cases.

In your layout, make sure you **do not** set `textMultiline` as input type, then use the following code:

```
mEditText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Or specify a lower value if you want
mEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
```

Comment: Did the trick! Thank you!
I bet I tried these attributes in XML…

Comment: Awwwwww...some!