# How to Make EditText Box Height Expand

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTweetReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Discuss up to 140 characters"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLength="140"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/theReviewBarButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Submit Review"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSort"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When that EditText box gets to the end, I want it to wrap to the next line.  Right now, it just keeps going right moving everything left off screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Word-Wrap EditText text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276380/android-word-wrap-edittext-text)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Similar to another question:

[Android Word-Wrap EditText text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276380/android-word-wrap-edittext-text)

Here's some example XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/compose_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:maxLines="4" />
```

Comment: I looked at other answers but missed the biggest thing:  `textMultiLine`  thanks, marking correct.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"  

this will makes work

Comment: Great attribute which I am not aware of. Thinking to update the maxlines dynamically based on the string count.

Answer (score 41):

Assume that you just want to have one line at first then expand it to 5 lines and you want to have maximum 10 lines.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etMessageBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:hint="@string/message_edit_text_hint"
    android:lines="5"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"/>
```

By increasing `android:lines` you can define expand it how many lines.

Comment: What if we want to start with 4 lines and have the text scroll upward when the user has entered more than 4 lines worth of text?

Answer (score 12):

Just add android:lines="6" to your edittext

```
 <Edittext
      android:id="@+id/edt_address"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
      android:maxLines="6"             
      android:lines="6"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:gravity="left"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/"edittext01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="100"
    android:maxLines="10"/>
```

Comment: It would be really good if you could add some commentary to add context to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need your `EditText` height set to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

&

```
android:lines="5"
```

This did the trick for me inside `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line form your EditText

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

and add this line with number of lines required by you

```
android:lines="2"
```

Hope this helps you