# android edittext wrap text

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, word-wrap

This is my Edittext layout

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="text|textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dp" android:text="S"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </EditText>
```

If I try to put textSize="30dp", for example, the edittext is not resized and the letter is trouncated.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Firs your textSize should be in `sp` units instead of `dp`, second I have not a clear idea of what you want to achieve :)

Comment: this is a screenshot [link](http://i41.tinypic.com/s2vg37.png), the edittext is not resized and the box is bigger of text

Answer (score 4):

Removing the `android:inputType` attribute from your Edittext will solve your problem. I don't what is the relation between this attribute and wrapping the text. but i faced this problem too.

Update:
Add `textMultiLine` to your `android:inputType` attribute.

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286921/2294985

Comment: I just tried this.  It makes the "enter" key just put a line break in the edit text.  I'm looking for a way to enter a long line of text and have it wrap as opposed to scrolling horizontally.  I'll be back if I find anything.

Comment: Scrolling horizontal is activated by the `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` attribute. the enter button puts line break because the inputType is textMultiLine

Answer (score 0):

add below code to editText tag for wrap editText:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
```