# EditText word wrap

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What i want is when the user enters more text than which fits into a single line, the `EditText` wraps the line, increases it height automatically and shows the not fitting text in the next line. The `EditText` should not be scrollable horizontally.

I read lots of questions related to this, but none of them helped. Currently the `EditText` above does not wrap the lines, and can be scrolled horizontally. I tested on Android 4.2 and 4.4.

**EDIT:** added complete layout.

**EDIT2:**

Sorry, this is my fault. I change the input type programatically in my code:

```
mEditText.setInputType(mInputTypes.get(question.getType()));
```

So with this line, i have overriden the input type from xml. I modified the code, and the `multiLine` input type indeed works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have removed all unnecessary attributes and put only required attribute android:maxLines="20",

So it looks like this,

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="20" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did the same, but it is still not working. :(

Comment: Post your complete xml

Comment: Thanks, it indeed works (see my edit in the OP). The required attribute here is `inputType` actually.

Comment: Ohh..Sorry.. i removed that. Glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

add `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` and `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` this attribute in `EditText` [from this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276380/android-word-wrap-edittext-text)

```
<EditText
    android:id ="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width ="0dip" 
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" 
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines ="4" 
    android:maxLength ="2000"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me:

```
EditText someedittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.someedittext);
someedittext.setMaxWidth(someedittext.getWidth());
```